# Removing a Suggestion in Google Maps Search

Tags: google-chrome, maps

I created a private map in Google Maps and while I was creating it used a search term. Now whenever I open any saved map in Google Maps and click in the search bar, that search term appears at the top.

How can I delete only this one search term?

I've looked at the Google Activity page and tried making lots of other searches in the hope it just disappears, but it just stays there. Any help gratefully received.